# How do I limit the user API response to the current user with Django Tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to use Django Tastypie to create a simple API. I have custom auth (not really that custom since it's copied directly from their example) that exposes only `entries` from the current user. It returns all users though, and I only want it to expose the one that's logged on. Right now I'm using this as my `api.py`:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        excludes = ['password', 'is_superuser']
        resource_name = 'user'
       authentication=MultiAuthentication(SessionAuthentication(),ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization=DjangoAuthorization()
        allow_methods=['get']

class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        authentication=MultiAuthentication(SessionAuthentication(),ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization=UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization()
```

And this for the `UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization`

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized


class UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        # This assumes a ``QuerySet`` from ``ModelResource``.
        return object_list.filter(user=bundle.request.user)

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        # Is the requested object owned by the user?
        return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user

    def create_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        # Assuming they're auto-assigned to ``user``.
        return object_list

    def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user

    def update_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        allowed = []

        # Since they may not all be saved, iterate over them.
        for obj in object_list:
             if obj.user == bundle.request.user:
                allowed.append(obj)

        return allowed

    def update_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user

    def delete_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        # Sorry user, no deletes for you!
        raise Unauthorized("Sorry, no deletes.")

    def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise Unauthorized("Sorry, no deletes.")
```

If I apply that Authentication to the `UserResource` in `api.py`, like I am for the `EntryResource` it gives me errors. I can provide more detail if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your filter in a new `CustomUserAuthorization`, check the details of this implementation and check the Tastypie documentation about Authorization.

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized


class CustomUserAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        # This you put your filter
        return object_list.filter(id=bundle.request.user.id)

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        # This is to check the current user
        return bundle.obj.id == bundle.request.user.id

    def create_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise Unauthorized("Sorry, not allowed.")

    def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise Unauthorized("Sorry, not allowed.")

    def update_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise Unauthorized("Sorry, not allowed.")

    def update_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        # Only update your details
        return bundle.obj.id== bundle.request.user.id

    def delete_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise Unauthorized("Sorry, no deletes.")

    def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise Unauthorized("Sorry, no deletes.")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks man! Worked like a charm.. that wasn't my actual issue though :/

Any ideas how to troubleshoot a 401 when doing an Ajax post? I tried adding the csrf token, but I'm not sure if I am correctly, etc... it's not really giving me any details in javascript the console though.

Comment: 401? Check if you are sending the correct cookies. There is no csrf token as it is a REST API.