# What's wrong with my tastypie POST request?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm getting a 401 when trying to do a post in ajax with Tastypie. I can log a GET to the console, and they use the same authentication. How can I debug?

Here's my javascript:

```
// sending a csrftoken with every ajax request
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: true, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});

//this is the get request, which works fine
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8080/data/api/v1/user/?format=json",
   success: function(data){
console.log(data);
}
});

$(function() {
  $('#newEntry').click(function() {
   var table=$("#entryName").val(); 
   var d = JSON.stringify({
    "name":entry,
    "user":"http://localhost:8080/data/api/v1/user/?format=json"
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: d,
      success: function(r) {console.log(r); },
      error: function(r){console.log(r); },
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/data/api/v1/entry/',
      cache:false
    });
  });
});
```

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269427/how-do-i-limit-the-user-api-response-to-the-current-user-with-django-tastypie/24269855#24269855) question earlier, as I thought it would help, but it hasn't. It has more context, namely about what I'm using for auth, but I can provide more detail if needed.

Comment: Just as a guess, the REST endpoint is probably not set up to allow POST requests. I don't know how it works with TasteyPie, but that's how it works with DRF.

Answer (score 0):

`401` usually means you aren't authorized to access that resource, or there is a CSRF issue.

Two things spring to mind

1. You are not authenticated. Are you logged in(`SessionAuthentication`), or are you sending the username and api key with your request(`ApiKeyAuthentication`).
2. If #1 is not the problem, then maybe it's because the csrf token has not been set. Django does not set the token for all requests. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) -

> If your view is not rendering a template containing the csrf_token template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces setting of the cookie: [ensure_csrf_cookie()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie).

I'm guessing that #2 is the more like scenario. You can either wrap your views in the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator, or use a middleware to do that for all requests. Or you could use the api key for authentication, as it does not look like it checks for csrf token(not really sure, but I'm looking at the tastypie code and I don't see any csrf checks.)